# Visiting a Url in cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have a deployed application. when i open the url the website opens just fine. when i try to test it using cypress i become

```
cy.visit() failed trying to load:

https://test.windows.net/en-US/home

The response we received from your web server was:

  > 404: Not Found

This was considered a failure because the status code was not 2xx.
If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: failOnStatusCode: false
In my code i just have

cy.visit(`https://test.windows.net/en-US/home`);
```

on the online documentation i found that failOnStatusCode could be used with `cy.request` but not with `cy.visit`

Edit:
When I perform the same steps on chrome everything works just fine

Comment: `cy.visit()` throws that error when it receives a non-2xx response. Are you able to manually reach that page? Using the same browser + setup as cypress does? I'd also look into setting a global base URL, since sending the full URL is considered anti-pattern in Cypress. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Setting-a-global-baseUrl

Comment: Yes, see update